# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code 400

Tags: веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, angular2

В общем, есть Web API и Angular морда.

На стороне Web Api я прописал:

```
   services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", b =>
                    {
                        b.AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowCredentials();
                    }
                );
            });

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

В Angular сервисе, шлю запрос на контроллер:

```
this._httpClient.get(`Адрес API`);
```

И ловлю ошибку:

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code 400

Что я упустил?

Адрес по которому я стучусь успешно работает через PostMan и получается ответ.

Аутентификация используется виндовая.

Не знаю, есть ли взаимосвязь, но при запуске Angular приложения увидел вот такие ошибки еще:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred
>   during a cryptographic operation.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapiCore(Byte*
>   pbProtectedData, UInt32 cbProtectedData, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy,
>   UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapi(Byte[]
>   protectedSecret)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor.Decrypt(XElement
>   encryptedElement)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager:Error:
>   An exception occurred while processing the key element ''.
>
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred
>   during a cryptographic operation.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapiCore(Byte*
>   pbProtectedData, UInt32 cbProtectedData, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy,
>   UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapi(Byte[]
>   protectedSecret)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor.Decrypt(XElement
>   encryptedElement)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.DecryptElement(XElement
>   element, IActivator activator)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.DeserializeDescriptorFromKeyElement(XElement
>   keyElement)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DefaultKeyResolver:Warning:
>   Key {7bdf260b-8494-42b9-a538-83e817cb9f36} is ineligible to be the
>   default key because its CreateEncryptor method failed.
>
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred
>   during a cryptographic operation.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapiCore(Byte*
>   pbProtectedData, UInt32 cbProtectedData, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy,
>   UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapi(Byte[]
>   protectedSecret)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor.Decrypt(XElement
>   encryptedElement)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.DecryptElement(XElement
>   element, IActivator activator)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.DeserializeDescriptorFromKeyElement(XElement
>   keyElement)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DeferredKey.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0()
>   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)    at
>   System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper
>   executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)    at
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyBase.get_Descriptor()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.CngGcmAuthenticatedEncryptorFactory.CreateEncryptorInstance(IKey
>   key)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyBase.CreateEncryptor()

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91102/discussion-on-question-by-iluxa1810-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected).